# Regex: Provide match for beginning of a sentence ignoring new lines

Tags: python, regex

```
string= "This is a sentence. Micky Mouse"

name= re.compile(f"\.?Micky Mouse")
name_match = name.search(string)
print(name_match)
```

I want to ensure that a match is only provided if "Micky Mouse" is at the beginning of a new sentence, i.e., only if it follows on a dot "."
However, there should also be a match irrespective of any new lines or spacings between "Micky Mouse" and the end of the previous sentence. So the following expression should also provide a match `print("This is a sentence. \nMicky Mouse")`

Comment: You may use: `(?:^|\. *)Micky Mouse`

Comment: you may want to read through the docs at some point — it's pretty straightforward: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match optional whitespace chars after the dot:

```
\.\s*Micky Mouse\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\.\s*` Match a dot and optional whitespace chars (that can also match a newline)
- `Micky Mouse\b` Match literally followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UXPbAu/1)

Answer (score 0):

The `\s` flag matches for all whitespace characters including `\n`.

Something like the following should do the trick

```py
re.compile("\.\s?Mickey Mouse")
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to solve the problem with '\n' but ignores the need that the last character before "Micky" has to be dot. 'This is a sentence \nMicky Mouse' will also be matched, even though there is no "." after "This is a sentence". Any ideas how to account for this?

Comment: I missed the `\` before the `.`, lol

Answer (score 0):

In order to be at the beginning of a sentence, and ignore any whitespace differences after it, prepend the match target with `(?:^|\.)\s*`.

- `(?:)`  -> it doesn't create a group
- `^|\.`  -> either the beginning of the String `^` or `|` a literal dot `\.`
- `\s*`   -> any amount of whitespace, including newlines, spaces, tabs, etc.

```
import re

string= """This is a sentence. Micky Mouse. 
           Micky Mouse again. No Micky Mouse match here."""

pattern = re.compile(f"(?:^|\.)\s*Micky Mouse")
name_match = re.finditer(pattern, string)
print([match.group(0) for match in name_match])
```

output:

```
['. Micky Mouse', '. \n           Micky Mouse']
```